# I have imported all required packages but i am still not able to run this keylogger

Tags: python, smtp, syntax-error, keylogger

```
from smtpd import SMTPServer
import smtplib, ssl

def sendEmail(message):
    smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
    port = 465
    sender_email = "fakemail@gmail.com"
    password = "password"
    receiver_email = "fakemail@gmail.com"

    context = ssl.create_default_context()

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,port)
    server.ehlo() 
    server.starttls(context=context) 
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)

except Exception as e:
        print(e)
finally:
        server.quit()
```

got this error while running the code

```
name 'smtp_server' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dhruvsahgal/Desktop/dhruv_practice/project1/send_email.py", line 24, in <module>
    server.quit()
NameError: name 'server' is not defined
```

Please help me find out what the error is
I am running this on mac os in vs code

Comment: you define smtp_server in your function but never call the function so maybe try to put the try-except-finally part inline of the function if its part of it

Comment: didn't work 
it shows a green line under context, port, smtp_server, sender_email, password, receiver_email and message as 
they are "not defined"

Comment: Calling the function won't help, because `smtp_server` is used outside the scope where it would be defined.

Comment: try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,port)
this parameter that you are passing to the function is not defined

Comment: how do i define it then?